# Calling AWS Cognito Form Lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a publicly exposed lambda that allows users to sign up with my site backed by AWS Cognito; or at least I'm trying to.

```
func (d *deps) handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    req := Request{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(request.Body), &req)
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: 400}, UserErrResponse
    }


    session := session2.Must(session2.NewSessionWithOptions(session2.Options{Profile: "default"}))

    svc := cognitoidentityprovider.New(session, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-east-1"))

    input := &cognitoidentityprovider.SignUpInput{
        Password: aws.String(req.Password),
        Username: aws.String(req.Email),
        ClientId: aws.String("**myclientid**"),
    }

    _, err = svc.SignUp(input)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("unable to sign up user with err=%v", err.Error())
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: 500}, UserErrResponse
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: 200}, nil
}
```

This lambda hangs and eventually times out on the "svc.SignUp(input)" line. No error. No feedback. No nothing.

My initial thought was that the lambda does not have permission to connect to Cognito so I gave it all permission as a first debugging measure:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "cognito_sign_in" {
  name   = "${local.name_prefix}LambdaCogntioPolicy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action   = [
          "cognito-identity:*",
          "cognito-idp:*",
          "cognito-sync:*",

        ]
        Effect   = "Allow",
        Resource = "*"
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

This did not help. Still hangs. What am I missing here?

The goal is to write my own lambda's for signing users up, signing users in, and resetting passwords; all backed by Cognito.

Comment: Does a read-only api call like [ListGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.ListGroups) return the expected result? Also FYI, although not related to your error, the go SDK has a newer version: [aws-sdk-go-v2](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/).

Comment: @fedonev ListGroups() does work although it seems to take a very long time: 7 seconds. I increased the lambda timeout to 30 seconds thinking that maybe the signIn() call takes longer but it still times out.